# Why the generated IL code for a pointer and ref is same but signatures are different?

Tags: c#, pointers, il, ref

I'm trying to figure out how to reproduce the behaviour of `ref` modifier in C#.

I have two methods:

```
static void Foo(ref int x)
{
     x = 25;
}

unsafe static void Foo(int* x)
{
    *x = 25;
}
```

Even though the generated IL codes for these two method are the same, the signatures are different:

The code for `Foo(ref int)`:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Foo(int32& x) cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   25
  IL_0004:  stind.i4
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

And the code for `Foo(int*)`

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Foo(int32* x) cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   25
  IL_0004:  stind.i4
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

So my question is, why the signatures are different while the generated codes are same? Can't the same work be performed using pointers?

**Note:** I compiled this code `Visual Studio 2015 Preview`, `Debug Mode`.

Comment: Both functions are provided an address to write to.   What do you think should be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the two methods have the same IL for their implementation is that the [`stind.i4` opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stind_i4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> stores an int32 value at the supplied address (type native int, *, or &).

This means that OpCode works for both a pointer and a reference, since they are both effectively just addresses to the storage location.  Since the work being done is identical other than the type being passed in, but the same OpCode applies, the method bodies end up being identical.

This does not mean they are interchangable methods, however.  They require calling in different manners, which is why the signatures differ.  Also, this is just the intermediate language - they will likely get compiled to machine code differently by the JIT.

Comment: I'm also thinking that `ref` keyword can be used with classes as well and  it's not possible to declare a pointer to managed type.might that be the reason?

Comment: @Selman22 Well, the op codes would change if it was a managed type, so they wouldn't be the same.  Using pointers wouldn't work at all, and pointers also requires changes in runtime permissions, etc.

Comment: @Selman22 Note that you'll get the same body if you use `out` as well (and the same IL signature as ref!)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that IL is not the end result of compilation, it is a portable intermediate format that feeds into the final compiler stages.

IL instructions change behavior based on the type of the item(s) on top of the operand stack.  The JIT compiler performs type analysis and determines whether `stind` is working with a pointer or reference, just as it determines whether `add` is working on integers or floating-point or pointers.